# solr word document stemming

Tags: solr, lucene

Solr allows to index word documents through TIKA - ExtractingRequestHandler. Document is saved in `"content"` field type `"text_general"`. But information in document is not stemmed and stop words not removed, even if analyzers are present.
What could be the reason?

As a quick fix we read document from solr and apply explicitly lucene `analyzers(parsing,stop words, stemming)`.
Thanks

Comment: can you show your field + analyzer configuration

Comment: did you check the same in analysis page? solr web page....

Comment: field information ->   <field name="content" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"  termVectors="true" /> field type information

Comment: <fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" >
      <analyzer>
 <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
 <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory"/>
     </analyzer>

Comment: <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
          <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>

Comment: <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory"/> 
      </analyzer>

Comment: using analysis page seems to work as I have set "indexed=true" for field name "content" .